# How to find AUC in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, auc

I have two files: predictions.csv and target.csv.

**Format of predictions.csv:**

```
SampleID,Target
t1,-1.0454370703147253e-05
t2,-0.48161680725663214
t3,8.1420547483708091e-06
.
.
.
t4950,-6.4382307796971309e-05
```

**Format of target.csv:**

```
#SampleID,Target [0 or 1],Details [-1 or 4]
1,0,4
2,0,4
3,0,4
.
.
.
4950,0,4
```

**What I tried:**

```
import numpy
from sklearn import metrics

target_file = "target.csv"
prediction_file = "predictions.csv"

true = numpy.genfromtxt(target_file,delimiter=',')
scores = numpy.genfromtxt(prediction_file, delimiter=',')

scores = scores[1:,1:]
true = true[:,2:]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(true, scores)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-d4232bf9bd64>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/MyAccount/Documents/Spyder/Connectomics/myauc.py', wdir='C:/Users/MyAccount/Documents/Spyder/Connectomics')

  File "C:\Users\MyAccount\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\MyAccount\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/MyAccount/Documents/Spyder/Connectomics/myauc.py", line 19, in <module>
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(true, scores)

  File "C:\Users\MyAccount\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 477, in roc_curve
    y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)

  File "C:\Users\MyAccount\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 297, in _binary_clf_curve
    raise ValueError("Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified")
```

How can I find the AUC?

Edit:
Added the possible values which target.csv columns can take.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of your code, and the full error traceback.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited that.

Comment: The problem is it is expecting the target to be `0` or `1`. Here you have `4` in your data sample. What values can it take on?

Comment: @DavidMaust Added that.